# Who was goddess Sita's father? Why are there multiple stories? Which one should we believe?

Tags: ramayana, ravana, sita

There have been many accounts as to who actually was the father of goddess Sita.

Contrary to what Valmiki's Ramayana says, some of them states that Sita was Ravana's first child whom he abandoned; when it was prophesized that his first child will destroy him.

According to another version; Sita was the reincarnation of Vedavati (the learned woman) who cursed Ravana when he misbehaved with her.

Who was goddess Sita's father?

Why are there multiple versions on Sita's birth?

Which one should we believe in?

Comment: As far as I know, Janak was sitas father

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We should go by the the Ramayana. If it says Janaka is the father, then we should believe that. However, Ramayana says, King Janaka found Sita in a furrow buried under the earth:

> अथ मे कृषतः क्षेत्रम् लांगलात् उत्थिता मम
>   क्षेत्रम् शोधयता लब्ध्वा नाम्ना सीता इति विश्रुता | [VR - 1.66.13,14]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Later, when I was ploughing the ritual field then raised by the plough [from the furrow is a baby girl... since she is] gained while consecrating the ritual-field, she is named as Seetha, and thus she is renowned

So as there are no direct description of how Sita appeared under earth, other texts add up how that furrow ended up there. For example, the Sanghadasa's [Jaina version of Ramayana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama_in_Jainism) says Sita was actually daughter of Ravana. When he heard from the astrologer that the first child would ruin his lineage, he gave her up and his men buried her in a furrow under the ground where Janaka later found her.

Regarding Vedavati, as per Skanda Puran she became the *maya* Sita whom Ravan kidnapped. Vedavati after giving up her life in fire due to Ravana's ill behaviour became Swaha, the wife of Agni. And when Ravana tried to kidnap Sita, it was Swaha who actually took the place of Her. So Vedavati was not the actual Sita, but the *maya* Sita.

Similarly, there are many other versions and stories. But when no authentic information is available, we should consider Janaka as Maa Sita's father. Because at the least, Janaka raised Her and as a parent wedded Her to Shri Rama. Even Mahabharat describes Sita as Janaka's daughter and says She was made by a rishi:

> विदेहराजॊ जनकः सीता तस्यात्मजा बिभॊ
>   यां चकार सवयं तवष्टा रामस्य महिषीं परियाम [MB - 3.258.9]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Janaka was the king of Videha. Sita was his daughter. *Rishi* Twashta had created Her desiring to maker Her the beloved wife of Shri Rama

So there are many different stories and reasons. We just need to believe what the prominent texts like Ramayana and Mahabharat say.

**Reference**:
[Vedavati](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedavati#Prophecy)

Answer (score 1):

Valmiki Ramayana is the authentic text on Ramayana.

While narrating the details of her marriage with Sri Rama, Sita says that while tilling the land, Janaka found her in the land.

> तस्य लान्गल हस्तस्य कर्षतः क्षेत्र मण्डलम् |
> अहम् किल उत्थिता भित्त्वा जगतीम् नृपतेः सुता || २-११८-२८
>
> "While he was furrowing a territory of land, holding a plough in his hand, it is so said that I came forth, splitting up the land, as a daughter of that king."
>
> अनपत्येन च स्नेहाद् अन्कम् आरोप्य च स्वयम् |
> मम इयम् तनया इत्य् उक्त्वा स्नेहो मयि निपातितः || २-११८-३०
>
> "Placing me personally in his lap with affection, that childless king Janaka called one as his daughter, and was very fond of me since then."

Valmiki Ramayana is silent as to who the biological father of Sita.

&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

Janaka says in Bala Kanda as follows:

> भू तलात् उत्थिता सा तु व्यवर्धत मम आत्मजा || १-६६-१४
>
> वीर्य शुल्का इति मे कन्या स्थापिता इयम् **अयोनिजा** |
>
> "Hers is **a non-uterine birth** as she surfaced from the surface of the earth, but fostered as my own soul-born girl and I determined [to giver her in marriage to a bridegroom where his] boldness is the only bounty, [I receive in that marriage.."

---

We have to remember that Sita was **an ayOnija**, born out of uterine.

If we take it as a story then there would be no problem.  The concept of **ayOnija, born out of uterine** can be accepted.

If we think in a scientific manner, then we can presume that she was born out of an advanced genetic scientific experiment.

A test tube baby??